# How to exit a makefile without running other tasks, with a successful exit-code?

Tags: shell, makefile, exitstatus

I've got a makefile that has a 'contingency step' to bootstrap the environment if the task is run without prior, critical setup:

```
bootstrap: ensure_opam_switch_once build


.ONESHELL:
$(FRONTEND_OPAM_SWITCH):
    @echo ''
    @echo "$(bold)[make bootstrap]$(sgr0) An opam-switch doesn't exist for frontend/, creating one ..."
    OPAMYES=true $(MAKE) init
    opam exec --sw="${FRONTEND_DIR}" -- $(MAKE) bootstrap
    @EXIT_CODE=$$?
    @exit $$EXIT_CODE

ensure_opam_switch_once: | $(FRONTEND_OPAM_SWITCH)

init:
    # this does critical first-time setup

build:
    # ... everything else happens here
```

The issue is that several shell-variables need to be set for the rest of the makefile — and I'm not guaranteed to know those variables. (`opam` sets up some stuff with `eval`; think `rbenv`, `nvm`, `pyenv`, etc.)

My plan/hack here is to *re-execute* the make-task after setup, with those shell-variables configured in the environment make is invoked from. (In the above example, that's the `opam exec` line.)

However, my issue at the moment is that, if the sub-make exits with success, then my `@exit $$EXIT_CODE` doesn't result in Make exiting! It continues to run and attempt to execute other dependents, which obviously fails because the *outer* Make invocation doesn't have any of the necessary shell-environment.

Is there a way to *stop Make* with a successful exit-code?

Comment: I don't know of a (non-kludge) way to abort Make and return a non-error value, but this looks a little like the XY problem. Can you explain a little more clearly which things you want Make to do, in what order and under what circumstances?

Comment: The short answer is no, there is no way to stop make early with a successful error code.  Once it's started it will build all the targets in the part of the graph it starts with, or it will exit early with a failure.  You'll have to play a trick using recursive makefiles, such as @Beta or Renault suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You could use conditionals to hide or not parts of your Makefile. Example with a `PASS` make variable that defines what part of the Makefile shall be used:

```bash
$ cat Makefile
.PHONY: all

all:
ifeq ($(PASS),)
    @echo 'PASS = $(PASS), VAR = $(VAR)'
    export VAR=VAL; $(MAKE) PASS=1
else
    @echo 'PASS = $(PASS), VAR = $(VAR)'
endif

$ make
PASS = , VAR = 
export VAR=VAL; make PASS=1
make[1]: Entering directory 'foo'
PASS = 1, VAR = VAL
make[1]: Leaving directory 'foo'
```

Answer (score 0):

Fwiw, the following stops `make`, but with exit code 1 "failure", not success as you want:

```
... $(MAKE) exit-make

exit-make:
    $(error exit-make)
.PHONY: exit-make

#   example --
bigtmp=`find ~ -name 'tmp*.n*'`; \
if [[ $$bigtmp ]]; then echo $$bigtmp; $(MAKE) exit-make; fi

...mk:29: *** exit-make.  Stop.
```